# How to assign value to a firedac macro and have fastreport.loadfromfile recognize it

Tags: delphi, macros, firedac, fastreport

How to assign value to a firedac macro and have fastreport.loadfromfile recognize it.

I have a sql with this format

```
select * from tbl1 where &condition order by id
```

When i run

```
Report.LoadFormFile (file1.fr3);
Report.PrepareReport (False);
```

Comment: If you are talking about how do you filter the data that FastReports prints out, you do it by setting the SQL in firedac before you start the report. You filter the database, not FastReport.

Comment: Yes. It is true.but I have to make a single pdf from at least 10 individual reports. when I upload individual reports and prepare them with report.loadfromfile ('rptfile.fr3'); report.prepareReport (false); the queries do not exist or I do not know how to relate them